# Android Volley Post JSONObject to Jersey Web Service

Tags: android, post, jersey, android-volley, json

I spend many hours, reading all questions and answers but couldn't solve the problem.
The source code of android volley client :

```
 JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();

            jsonobject_one.put("mobileNumber", "mobileNumberValue");
            jsonobject_one.put("x", "I");

            JSONObject jsonobject_TWO = new JSONObject();
            jsonobject_TWO.put("value", "event");
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

            jsonobject.put("requestinfo", jsonobject_TWO);
            jsonobject.put("request", jsonobject_one);


            js.put("data", jsonobject.toString());

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

JsonObjectRequest strRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Server_Urls.URL_SEND_MOBILE_NUMBER,
                js, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject  response)
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                            // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
                        }
                    }
                })
        {
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strRequest);
```

The source code of jersey webservice :

```
@POST
    @Path("get_activation_code")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HashMap<String, String> getActivationCode(JSONObject param1){

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("mobileNumber", "1234");
        params.put("x", "x");

        return params;
    }
```

Logcat:

> 08-28 20:24:32.910    3282-3303/com.hb.app I/qtaguid﹕ Tagging socket
>   47 with tag 1e7db22900000000(511554089) for uid -1 failed errno=-2
>   08-28 20:24:32.930    3282-3303/com.hb.app
>   I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ tagSocketFd(47, 511554089, -1) failed
>   with errno-2 08-28 20:24:33.650    3282-3303/com.hb.app I/qtaguid﹕
>   Untagging socket 47 failed errno=-2 08-28 20:24:33.650
>   3282-3303/com.hb.app W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger﹕ untagSocket(47)
>   failed with errno -2 08-28 20:24:33.842    3282-3303/com.hb.app
>   D/Volley﹕ [95] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for
>   request=<[ ]
>   http://10.0.2.2:8080/GmServer/gme/registration/get_activation_code
>   0x1e7db229 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=8875], [size=6441], [rc=500],
>   [retryCount=0] 08-28 20:24:33.884    3282-3303/com.hb.app E/Volley﹕
>   [95] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for
>   http://10.0.2.2:8080/GMServer/gme/registration/get_activation_code
>   08-28 20:24:40.743    3282-3282/com.hb.app D/Volley﹕ [1]
>   Request.finish: 33086 ms: [ ]
>   http://10.0.2.2:8080/GMeServer/giftme/registration/get_activation_code
>   0x1e7db229 NORMAL 1

Note that I tried almost all equivalent questions in StackOverflow with no answer.

Comment: response code 500 means server failed. Try to print your requests before you send it and make sure all values that you're trying to pass are correct. If everything on your side is fine, then that would be the server problem.

Comment: Perhaps you send request to 2 server applications? .../GMServer and .../GiftMeServer? Why so? Moreover, where are they hosted? Localhost? And your android app run on real phone or AVD?

Comment: @BNK I renamed /GiftMeServer to /GMServer in logcat, sorry, that was my mistake, So there's only one server. Also the application run on AVD with localhost server. I put a breakpoint at the first line in `getActivationCode` method in server but it is not raised

Comment: @TreyCai I don't know how can I do that. Would you please explain it

Comment: @BzH: try using `request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: Moreover, test access `http://10.0.2.2:8080/GmServer/...` from the web browser in your AVD to check if can access or not